# Magento - Price including tax

Tags: magento

In Magento I have this setting System > Config > Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation > Default County set to 'None'.

This is because when users add something to their cart I need the price to initially show excluding TAX/VAT until they choose a shipping country.

The problem is I then need to echo products prices including tax on the product pages but finding this impossible as every method I try then shows the price excluding Tax/VAT ie:

```
echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax,true,false)
```

Any ideas how to show the price including tax regardless of what this setting is in the config?

Comment: How can you show the price including Tax on the product pages? The customer hasn't chosen a country there either, has he?

Comment: Do you want to exclude tax/vat for products. Then for certain or 1 country you want to add tax/vat when a user selects this country for shipping?